# Python IndexError looping through array

Tags: python

Im trying to ensure each row has zero mean for a matrix of arbitrary dimensions. However Im getting IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2 when running the code below. Im iterating over values within the dimensions of Z only so I don't see how I could be attempting to index outside the dimensions of Z.

```
import numpy as np

def center_rows(Z):
     """Ensures each row has zero mean.
       Takes a matrix of arbitrary shape and subtracts from each row   the mean value of that row."""
 Zc = Z

 for row in Z:
     avg = np.mean(Z[row])
     Zc[row] = Z[row] - avg

 return Zc
```

Comment: Say, `Z = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]`. The first `row == [1,2,3]`. Does `Z[row]` make sense? It may make sense for multidimensional NumPy arrays, but is it what you really want?

Comment: I tried changing it to for row in range(len(Z)) instead but it doesen't fix anything.

Comment: please post Z, and fix indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a thought but usually you don't want to use python loops over Numpy arrays. You could get rows with 0 mean using just Numpy which would ideally skip the loop

```
Z - np.mean(Z,axis = 1)[:,None]
```

Also I'm not the most informed about how things work but `Zc = Z` may just point to the same array. At least when I tested it modifying either one modified the other so maybe adding.

```
Zc = Z.copy()
```

would help.

Edit: [:,None] just adds an extra dimension to the mean array. You can test it easily.

```
import numpy as np

test = np.array([1,2,3])

test.shape
Out[3]: (3,)

test[:,None].shape
Out[4]: (3, 1)
```

By having the same number of dimensions you can subtract the means directly from the array without the for loop.

Comment: Could you explain what the line np.mean(Z,axis = 1)[:,None] does exactly? Particularly the [:,none] part.